# Windows Phone 8 Databinding Textbox with MVVM and selection from a ListView

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, data-binding

So, not to beat a dead horse, I understand how to data-bind using MVVM, but I am beating my head against the wall on this particular problem.

My Windows Phone app uses Units, like inches, millimeters, feet... etc.
I am trying to make it possible for the end user to change the units at any point in the equation and convert on the spot.  So for instance, I have a TextBox entry for the value then to the right I have a another TextBox which has the units.

I have a collection of units:

```
public class cUnit
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Abb {get;set;}
  public double Mulitplier {get;set;}
}
```

So when a user clicks on the Units TextBox, I expand the ListBox and collapse the Panorama.  Once a Unit is selected, I collapse the Listbox and show the Panorma.
Here is where the problem is.
In generation one, I used a Case Statement to look at the Name of the TextBox that was clicked on.  I then hard-coded the appropriate PropertyValue so that when I received the cUnit back from the ListBox I could update the property in the ViewModel.
I know this is wrong, but I can't figure out a way around it.  Keep in mind that I have a lot of opportunities to change units, so I would like to have just one "Change-Unit" method.

Here is some of the "Bad" code:
Got-Focus Method

```
private void txt_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)   {
      tb = (TextBox)sender;
      lbUnits.SelectedIndex = -1;
      LengthUnits.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
      Panorama.Visibility =System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;            
}
```

This is what happens when a unit is selected from the ListView

```
private void lbUnits_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tb == null || lbUnits.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

        ViewModels.cUnit unit = (ViewModels.cUnit)lbUnits.SelectedItem;

        switch (tb.Name)
        {
            case "txtUnits1":
                App.ViewModel.Unit1 = unit;
                break;
            case "txtUnits2":
                App.ViewModel.Unit2 = unit;
                break;
            etc... (txtUnit53...)   you get the picture
        }

        LengthUnits.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        Panorama.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        tb = null;
    }
```

I was hoping there is a better way.  I am totally willing to re-write this from scratch, since I need to add another 20 or so items to my app.
I tried getting the **BindingExpression** but once I get it, I still can't seem to find the property to assign the unit to.

Any help would be appreciated.  If you would like to see how the OLD app works you can download it from the store.  Just search for ***Key Knife*** and pick the ***Calculator***.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after more research this is what I found.  I can use `GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)` to get the Expression.
From there I can get the `ParentBinding` which will then get me to the `PropertyPath` of the binding.

I used this information to set the `Binding` of the `ListBox.SelectedItem` like this:

```
private void txt_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox) sender;
    BindingExpression BE = tb.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    Binding B = BE.ParentBinding;
    PropertyPath P = B.Path;

    Binding NewBinding = new Binding(P.Path.Replace(".Abb", ""));
    NewBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TowWay;
    lbUnits.SetBinding(ListBox.SelectedItemProperty, NewBinding);

    //Hide Panorama
    Panorama.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    // Show ListBoxGrid
    LengthUnits.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Now all I have to do on `lbUnits.SelectionChanged` is reverse the hiding and showing of the Panorama and ListBoxGrid.

Hope this helps someone